# How does $(this) know what my target is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How does `$(this).keyup` know I want the keyup listener associated with the `#searchString` input, and not the parent div?  Doesn't `$(this)` represent the parent div?  I dumped out `$(this)` to the console, and it looks like an object for the parent div.

**Long story short:**

How is this working?  `$(this).keyup`

Instead of explicitly saying:  `$('#searchString').keyup` ??

```
$('<div id="msg">' + <input id="searchString" name="searchString" type="text" value="" /> + '</div>').dialog({

    open: function () {

        $(this).keyup(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER)
                $('#btnFind').click();
            return false;
        })

    },

    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Find",
            id: "btnFind",
            icon: "ui-icon-search",
            click: function () {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) may be a good read.

Comment: event bubbling....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: insted of using this can u use id or class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some testing; here are my observations:

- `$(this)` is representative of the parent `<div id="msg">`
- `$(this).keyup` is targeting any (and all) extra inputs I add to `<div id="msg">`
- I don't *think* this this is event [bubbling/capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616704/3772763) (the listeners are not nested):

  - `$('#btnFind').click();` is an *action* nested inside the keyup listener
  - the jQuery UI dialog button `id: "btnFind"` has a separate event listener, outside of the the parent `<div id="msg">`
- I went ahead and explicitly indicated the target for the listener:  `$('#searchString').keyup`

Who cares?

Well, I didn't think you could establish event listeners on inputs via the dialog open event.  I'm creating my dialog on-the-fly, and my assumption was that the input may not exist while the open event was trying to establish the event listener.